# GOMobile "event/touch" Packages

Tags: xcode, go, touch, gomobile

How can I use gomobile "event/touch" packages? I want to get respective touch co-ordinate, and this return touch co-ordinate will used in ios/android.

Please suggest how to do this. If any sample application in available please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the gomobile repo cover this now. Specially this one: `golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic`